# Preserving join table data when reseeding a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, has-and-belongs-to-many, seed

I'm reseeding a fairly large database with updated static data and updated values which users engage with. However, I've noticed that reseeding the database clears all join tables for Has_and_belongs_to_many tables (all other user data, and tables remains unchanged).

Has anyone worked out a way around this where the data will be preserved when reseeding?

I'm using Rails & Postgresql

Comment: If you're inserting new data as a part of your reseeding, you'll have to build those associations as well. Any associations left over from before seeding are conceptually suspect: incomplete, incorrect, etc. Also, when you say reseed are you talking about `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`? or some manual db load?

Comment: @jaydel I actually don't drop the tables. I simply write over the data with `rake db:seed`. And my seed file for each table looks like this: EG:  `Industry.destroy_all`, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE industries RESTART IDENTITY")`. `Industry.create(name: 'Accounting')` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above you will need to recreate the associations. You can do this fairly straight forward in your seed file.

You might also look into the [seed dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) gem. This will allow you to snapshot your HABTM relationships and then export them into your `db/seeds.rb` (or whatever) file.